# .NET Fastest way to iterate through rows in a datatable?

Tags: .net, performance, ado.net, datatable, iteration

Which is generally fastest when reading/comparing row info from a DataTable?

```
'assume dt as datatable'

'method 1'
dim i as int32
for i = 0 to dt.rows.count - 1
   ....
next

'method 2'
dim row as datarow
for each row in dt.rows
    ....
next
```

And if there's a difference, in what circumstances does it pay to use one over the other?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler expands For Each to a short while loop.

```
for each row in dt.rows
// expands to:
IEnumerator e = dt.rows.GetEnumerator()
while e.MoveNext()
    row = e.Current
```

So you pay a small amount of overhead. But for clarities sake, I'd still stick with For Each if you're only working on one row, and you aren't modifying the data set.

Answer (score 3):

In reality no difference.  Although you technically pay a small price in the foreach method, for going through the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: Yes, in my test harness the two methods only show a performance difference after about 100K iterations.

Answer (score 3):

The second would have a slight penalty. However as for circumstances, I persoanlly would always use method 2 for clarity of code. However, I would use method 1 if I ever need to do something such as accessing a next/previous row while analyzing the current row.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a difference, since GetEnumerator and MoveNext that get called in foreach-loop are virtual (calling requires going through a pointer) and thus can't be inlined. This overhead in reality is small, unless you do a **lot** of loops.

In some cases though the compiler will replace foreach with a for-loop (I believe when iterating over arrays).

I personally prefer foreach in my ASP.NET MVC code for clarity, as many have said here, but often use the for-loop too.
Joe Duffy recently posted an interesting article about the cost of enumerating
http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/09/21/the-cost-of-enumerating-in-net/

Answer (score 1):

@gdean232 is right - almost no difference at all.  If performance is an issue, using a  a SqlDataReader instead is noticeable faster.

Answer (score -2):

The foreach implementation is actually slightly faster than the standard for implementation, because each index array access needs to be bounds checked.  However, since the idiom:

```
for(int i =0; i < myArray.Count; ++i)
{
    // do something with myArray[i];
}
```

is common, the compiler looks for it as a special case and optimizes it, so it becomes faster.  However, any small deviation from that format (such as int len = MyArray.Count; for(int i =0; i< len; ++i)) won't be recognized, and will use the slower code.